# SQL Order by current day

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table like this an would like to order it beginning with the current dayname.

```
title   date_firstcall      totalViews  Tag
name A  2014-08-25 10:19:49     2   Monday
name B  2014-08-24 16:03:36     3   Sunday
name C  2014-08-24 14:54:47     2   Sunday
name C  2014-08-23 11:06:19     3   Saturday
name A  2014-08-23 00:05:35     16  Saturday
name B  2014-08-22 10:05:53     4   Friday
name A  2014-08-22 00:11:28     25  Friday
name C  2014-08-21 19:28:54     1   Thursday
name A  2014-08-21 08:44:05     13  Thursday
name C  2014-08-20 22:42:49     1   Wednesday
name D  2014-08-19 16:22:42     2   Tuesday
name A  2014-08-19 15:43:57     10  Tuesday
name B  2014-08-19 09:36:52     1   Tuesday
```

my not working SQL-statement:

```
SELECT title as Seite, DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE) AS diff,
 sum( if( Tag = 'Monday', totalViews, 0 ) ) AS Montag,
 sum( if( Tag = 'Wednesday', totalViews, 0 ) ) AS Mittwoch,
 sum( if( Tag = 'Tuesday', totalViews, 0 ) ) AS Dienstag,
 sum( if( Tag = 'Thursday', totalViews, 0 ) ) AS Donnerstag,
 sum( if( Tag = 'Friday', totalViews, 0 ) ) AS Freitag,
 sum( if( Tag = 'Saturday', totalViews, 0 ) ) AS Samstag,
 sum( if( Tag = 'Sunday', totalViews, 0 ) ) AS Sonntag
 FROM tmp  GROUP BY title ORDER BY diff
```

the result table shout start with the current day at first followed by the next day.
Like:

```
        Seite   current day     next day    Dienstag    Mittwoch Donnerstag     Freitag     Samstag
       name A        2            7           0           3        9               2            2
       name c        3            2           1           0        9               2            2
```

Thx for any hint in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide an example of the output that you want.

Comment: pls see last line in my question

Comment: The [WEEKDAY](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-weekday-function.php) function will get you your days in order.  If I understand your desired result, you'll need to look into pivoting.

Comment: Is `Tag` the same as `WEEKDAY(date_firstcall)`? Why do you need that column?

Comment: it's DAYNAME(date_firstcall) from my view-table. In this case here is not needed and not valid anymore. You cant use for ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WEEKDAY` to get the day of week as a number. Subtract the current day modulo 7, so it will wrap around, and then pivot this.

```
SELECT title,
       SUM(IF(WEEKDAY(date_firstcall) = WEEKDAY(NOW()), totalViews, 0)) AS current_day,
       SUM(IF((WEEKDAY(date_firstcall)-WEEKDAY(NOW()) % 7) = 1, totalViews, 0)) AS day_plus_1,
       SUM(IF((WEEKDAY(date_firstcall)-WEEKDAY(NOW()) % 7) = 2, totalViews, 0)) AS day_plus_2,
       SUM(IF((WEEKDAY(date_firstcall)-WEEKDAY(NOW()) % 7) = 3, totalViews, 0)) AS day_plus_3,
       SUM(IF((WEEKDAY(date_firstcall)-WEEKDAY(NOW()) % 7) = 4, totalViews, 0)) AS day_plus_4,
       SUM(IF((WEEKDAY(date_firstcall)-WEEKDAY(NOW()) % 7) = 5, totalViews, 0)) AS day_plus_5,
       SUM(IF((WEEKDAY(date_firstcall)-WEEKDAY(NOW()) % 7) = 6, totalViews, 0)) AS day_plus_6
FROM tmp
GROUP BY title
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ebac/1)

Here's how to use dynamic SQL to get the day names:

```
SET @sql = (SELECT CONCAT('
     SELECT title,
            SUM(IF(WEEKDAY(date_firstcall) = WEEKDAY(NOW()), totalViews, 0)) AS ', DAYNAME(NOW()),
    ',      SUM(IF((WEEKDAY(date_firstcall)-WEEKDAY(NOW()) % 7) = 1, totalViews, 0)) AS ', DAYNAME(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)),
    ',      SUM(IF((WEEKDAY(date_firstcall)-WEEKDAY(NOW()) % 7) = 2, totalViews, 0)) AS ', DAYNAME(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)),
    ',      SUM(IF((WEEKDAY(date_firstcall)-WEEKDAY(NOW()) % 7) = 3, totalViews, 0)) AS ', DAYNAME(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)),
    ',      SUM(IF((WEEKDAY(date_firstcall)-WEEKDAY(NOW()) % 7) = 4, totalViews, 0)) AS ', DAYNAME(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 DAY)),
    ',      SUM(IF((WEEKDAY(date_firstcall)-WEEKDAY(NOW()) % 7) = 5, totalViews, 0)) AS ', DAYNAME(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)),
    ',      SUM(IF((WEEKDAY(date_firstcall)-WEEKDAY(NOW()) % 7) = 6, totalViews, 0)) AS ', DAYNAME(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 DAY)),
    '       FROM tmp
     GROUP BY title'));
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ebac/4)

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL to do that. It will probably be easier to do it in the application language that calls SQL.

Comment: What does SQL-Server have to do with it? MySQL has `PREPARE` to create dynamic SQL.

Comment: I started with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25484337/sql-pivot-with-dayvalue-dealing-with-date-in-pivot-table-mysql-solution/25509978#25509978

Comment: thx a lot Barmar. I told you I'am a beginner. I do not know how to bring this in PHP to work. At the moment i do the following: 

 if ( ($result = @mysqli_query($link, $sql))  && (@mysqli_affected_rows($link)!==0) )  {
                     $entries = array();
                     while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            $entries[] = $row;
                     }
              $data = json_encode($entries);
              echo($data);